# I have a list if tuples. How can I turn it into a tabular format?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
myList=[('god', 14), ('waters', 8), ('let', 6), ('earth', 6), ('light', 5), ('called', 5), ('said', 4), ('firmament', 4), ('yielding', 4), ('seed', 4)]

print("Term       Frequency")
for ele1,ele2 in myList:
  print("{:<14}{}".format(ele1,ele2))
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it does not generate any output.

Comment: the code is working. see below.

Answer (score 2):

Code

```
myList = [('god', 14), ('waters', 8), ('let', 6), ('earth', 6), ('light', 5), ('called', 5), ('said', 4),
          ('firmament', 4), ('yielding', 4), ('seed', 4)]

print("Term       Frequency")
for ele1, ele2 in myList:
    print("{:<14}{}".format(ele1, ele2))
```

output

```
Term       Frequency
god           14
waters        8
let           6
earth         6
light         5
called        5
said          4
firmament     4
yielding      4
seed          4
```